# A particular example of solvable group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let be $m$ an integer, $m>0$, $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_t^{a_t}$. Define $f(n)=a_1+...+a_t$.
Let $G$ be a finite group and define $f(G)=\max\left\{\,f(\lvert g\rvert):g\in G\,\right\}$.

Is there a finite solvable group $G$ with $f(\exp (G))>3\,f(G)?$

And, in general, is there a finite solvable group $G$ with $f(\exp(G))>n\,f(G)$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: Why $3f(G)$? Do you know examples with $f({\rm exp}(G)) = 3f(G)$?

Comment: With Frobenuis group, we can construct a solvable group with $ f(exp(G))/f(G) \rightarrow 3$. But I don't know examples with $f(exp(G))=3f(G)$.

Comment: Which Frobenius groups bring the quotient close to $3$?

Comment: $H$ the semidirect product of a cyclic group $A=C_{p^{m}}$ by a cyclic group $B=C_{q^{n+1}}$ which induces an automorphism of order $q^{n}$ on $A$ ($p$ and $q$ primes appropriate). $N$ the nilpotent group $C_{l^{d}}$ with $l \neq p,q$.  Let $G=NH$ of Frobenius. If $n=m=d-1$, then $f(exp(G))=3d-1$ and $f(G)=d$

Comment: I doubt that this construction works: The cyclic group $N$ has an abelian automorphism group, so the non-abelian group $H$ cannot act faithfully on $N$. In particular, $H$ cannot act fixed-point-freely, as it should for $N$ being the Frobenius kernel.

Comment: Can we prove that $f(exp(G)) \leq k f(G)$ with $k$ constant( maybe $k=3$)?

Comment: Rather than asking a new question in the comments, you should either edit your question, or raise a new question. In addition, it could be useful to know *why* you are interested in these things.

Comment: I think $N$ should be a direct product of copies of $C_{l^d}$ rather than just $C_{l^d}$. I checked that the construction works for $d=2$ with $A=C_7$, $B=C_9$ and $N = C_4^6$, so it seems plausible that it works for higher $d$. Assuming that to be the case, I would say that the question is interesting!